# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "DataItem" of recursive query "testtable"

Tags: sql-server

I am executing the following statement:

```
;WITH testtable(strict,DataItem, description) AS
    (
        SELECT
            strict,
            LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1),
            STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '')
        from safezone where id = 12
        UNION all

    SELECT
        strict,
        LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1),
        STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '')
    FROM testtable
    WHERE
        description > ''
        
)


SELECT
    strict,
    DataItem
into testno FROM testtable
ORDER BY strict
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

...which finishes with the error...

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "DataItem" of recursive query "testtable".

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: CAST/CONVERT  the LEFT and STUFF parts to an appropriate data type for both selects, eg: `CAST(LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1) AS VARCHAR(x))

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, the data types in the top and bottom of queries in the `UNION ALL` don't match. Maybe, for example, `strict` and `barcode` are different data types. Where is the value of `barcode` even coming from, as well, it's not defined in your CTE `testtable`. Also, when you fix all that, the above will never finish executing; you have infinite recursion.

Comment: Honestly, this looks like you've overly simplified your SQL, and actually made it invalid, as there's several problems here.

Comment: Also FYI `;` is a statement terminator... not a begin statement.

Comment: My mistake is barcode, it is strict I edit the code.

Comment: Thank's guys for help, it was very helpful, so

Comment: Can I use this query to generate a view?